# Android gallery didnot show camera images in 4.4?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, gallery

I have activity which take picture to my AppFolder using camera, but pictures are not visible from android gallery. I'm almost sure that in below 4.4 version it was good

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

        imageFileName = ...
        File imageFileFolder = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/AppFolder/");
        imageFileFolder.mkdir();
        intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(
                MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/AppFolder/"
                        + imageFileName));

        photoTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.TAKE_PICTURE);
```